# compare two comma separated values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable which contains comma separated value '1,2,3'

and my table is as below

```
id    favourite_id
1     2,5,6
2     3,5,7
3     6,1,3
4     5,6,7
```

I want to check my variable against favourite_id column to find at least one value is common in favourite_id. so I want output of mysql query as below

```
id    favourite_id
1     2,5,6
2     3,5,7
3     6,1,3
```

I know that this is not normalized table structure but I am not able to change my database structure.I have googled a lot but could not found suitable solution.

Comment: your output is based on what exactly? why rows 3 and 4 not shown that had 6?

Comment: You'll find single value for ex: contains id `5`, something like that?

Comment: @Akam Based on the first line of the question, I guess the "checking" value was "1,2,3", which would return rows with the `id` of 1, 2 and 3 as these rows also have a 1, 2 or 3 in the `favourite_id` col.

Comment: @Akam I have variable which have value '1,2,3' in it so any one of of it should be there in favourite_id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found two solution with the use of REGEXP of mysql

(1)

```
`favourite_id` REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]3[[:>:]]' //faster then below
```

(2)

```
`favourite_id` REGEXP '(^|,)(1|2|3)(,|$)' //slower then above
```

Answer (score 4):

use `FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`

More detail: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
```

Comment: FIND_IN_SET will compare whole string and not each value in first operand so in my case if I compare '1,2,3' then output will be 0 result

Comment: then get all the results from the table, explode fav_ids and  query them one by one with loop, but that is not a good approach.

Comment: there is thousands of records in table so it is not suitable to select and loop over result and then compare