# Mysql intersect two strings

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
TableFinal

column id, with first row having value 1
column numbers, with first row having value `1,5,6,33,2,12,3,4,9,13,26,41,59,61,10,7,28`
```

And

```
TablePick

column id, with first row having value 1
column numbers, with first row having value 2,12,26,33
```

I want to check if the numbers from TablePick, column "selected" are contained in the column "numbers" of TableFinal.

I have to mention that in TablePick, the numbers in column "selected" are ordered ASC, while in TableFinal, the numbers in column "numbers" are shuffled.

Usually I would put each of these in an array using PHP and then intersect the 2 arrays and count the resulted array. But in MYSQL, it is not that simple, so practically I have no idea where to start.

Maybe I should create an ARRAY_INTERSECT function? Or do we have a simpler solution?

```
SELECT * FROM TablePick p RIGHT JOIN TableFinal f ON f.id=p.id WHERE ARRAY_INTERSECT(p.selected,f.numbers)
```

Comment: MySQL is not a panacea. Normally, this kind of analysis is done (I think) in application layer code.

Comment: There's no datatype `array` in MySQL

Comment: here is a similar question with an accepted answer at the bottom. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629176/compare-two-comma-separated-values-in-mysql

Comment: I suspect that data normalization can help to avoid such problems

Comment: What is the maximum number of values in a row in either table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say so, but your schema needs some serious maintenance: **NEVER EVER** store more than one information in one field, if you need to access them separately.

You need a pair of join tables, where instead of the first row `(1, "1,5,6,33,2,12,3,4,9,13,26,41,59,61,10,7,28")` you have the rows

```
(1,1)
(1,5)
(1,6)
(1,33)
...
```

and instead of the row `(1, "2,12,26,33")` you have the rows

```
(1,2)
(1,12)
(1,26)
(1,33)
```

Now you query is simply:

```
SELECT ... FROM TableFinal 
INNER JOIN TABLE TablePick ON TableFinal.number=TablePick.number
WHERE TableFinal.id=1
AND TablePick.id=1
```

**EDIT**

Please  understand, that even if this were possible without MySQL abuse, it would be a performance killer, once the number of rows start to rise: We are talking of n*m array intersects, if the tables have n and m rows respectivly.

Comment: Well, the example is not identical to my db, just somehow similar to my requirement. I was only looking for some way to intersect two strings like intersecting 2 arrays

Comment: It sounds like you are in need of some sort of substring logic to fetch some data from mess of DB where, otherwise with a good normalization, you can easily and efficient fetch the same data just using a couple of joins